# how to convert AsymmetricKeyPair to base64 encoding string in dart

Tags: dart, cryptography, pointycastle

I‘m a rookie in PointyCastle,how can I generate ecc **base64** key pairs with PointyCastle in dart

```dart
AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> generateKeyPair({curve = 'secp256r1'}) {
    var param = curve == 'secp256r1' ? ECCurve_secp256r1() : ECCurve_secp256k1();
    var keyParams = ECKeyGeneratorParameters(param);

    var random = FortunaRandom();
    random.seed(KeyParameter(_seed()));

    var generator = ECKeyGenerator();
    generator.init(ParametersWithRandom(keyParams, random));

    return generator.generateKeyPair();
}
Uint8List _seed() {
    var random = Random.secure();
    var seed = List<int>.generate(32, (_) => random.nextInt(256));
    return Uint8List.fromList(seed);
}
```

above I can generate a AsymmetricKeyPair object,how to get public base64 and  private base64 like my already done js bundle

```js
{"priKey":"CVK3r/UxdGCwQBjtn5vN/orUMxKf9E/1TlJzLkMz9t4=","pubKey":"BJH/mWJqgchGxXGA5/E79SsWRwVo3rpduBmD8FOs7UlKiK8PIvwrkCDvUcwhKdysW35OByPjoVcwFqg1NyumLKM="}
```

besides, at first I want to use my js bundle file in flutter android, but that would be very tough as I know

[how to use js bundle in flutter android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642716/how-to-use-js-bundle-in-flutter-android)

I also need to make sign and verify function with ecdsa in sha256

```dart
Signer signer = new Signer('SHA-256/ECDSA');
// 签名，参数：私钥，明文
ECSignature sign(String privateKeyStr, String txt) {
    SecureRandom random = _setRadom();
    // how to convert a plain txt to kTestBytes
    final Uint8List kTestBytes = new Uint8List.fromList([1, 2, 3]);

    // if I pass in base64 privateKey str, is the radix 64?
    ECPrivateKey privateKey = new ECPrivateKey(BigInt.parse(privateKeyStr, radix: 10), ecDomain);

    PrivateKeyParameter signParams = new PrivateKeyParameter(privateKey);
    signer.init(true, new ParametersWithRandom(signParams, random));
    ECSignature signature = signer.generateSignature(kTestBytes) as ECSignature;
    return signature;
}
// 验签
//  参数： 明文，签名，公钥
bool verify(txt, signature, publicKey) {
    // how to make the txt to kTestBytes
    var kTestBytes = txt
    signer.init(false, new PublicKeyParameter(publicKey));
    bool verify = signer.verifySignature(kTestBytes, signature);
    // print(verify);
    return verify;
}
// I don't know what this function actually do,as I know in other language ecdsa don;t need a random number.
SecureRandom _setRadom() {
    List<int> key = [67, 3, 241, 75, 143, 78, 115, 99, 21, 242, 180, 43, 26, 7, 194, 20];
    List<int> iv = [87, 117, 137, 182, 2, 199, 132, 230, 120, 12, 109, 177, 34, 197, 186, 206];
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(new Uint8List.fromList(key));
    ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter> paramsIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, new Uint8List.fromList(iv));
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom('AES/CTR/AUTO-SEED-PRNG')..seed(paramsIV);
    return random;
}
```

Any place can I find sample codes, these functions were changed by some copies on the internet。and I got many confuses list in the comment

Comment: *...as I know, ecdsa does not require randomness in other languages...*: The non-deterministic ECDSA algorithm requires randomness. Other platforms may use default implementations for the CSPRNG or they may use the deterministic variant. Regarding key import/export. What is the desired key format: raw, ASN.1/DER (e.g. X.509, PKCS#8, SEC#1), etc.?

Comment: kind like this
```js
{"priKey":"CVK3r/UxdGCwQBjtn5vN/orUMxKf9E/1TlJzLkMz9t4=","pubKey":"BJH/mWJqgchGxXGA5/E79SsWRwVo3rpduBmD8FOs7UlKiK8PIvwrkCDvUcwhKdysW35OByPjoVcwFqg1NyumLKM="}
```

Comment: I have a js bundle,which has all the funcitons accepting base64  string params and return base64 strings

Comment: *base64 string params* is not a description of the key format. Base64 is an encoding and can be applied to various formats. What you' ve posted is the Base64 encoded *raw private* key and the Base64 encoded *uncompressed public* key. You should make that more precise in your question.

Comment: ok ,I re-Edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EC keys are to be exported/imported as a Base64 encoded raw private key and as a Base64 encoded raw uncompressed public key.

First of all it can be stated that signing and verifying with the posted code works when a fresh key pair is generated:

```dart
AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> kp = generateKeyPair();
ECSignature signature = sign(kp.privateKey as ECPrivateKey, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
bool verified = verify("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", signature, kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey);
print(verified); // true
```

I.e. in the following I will focus on the import/export of the keys. The raw keys are encapsulated in `ECPrivateKey` and `ECPublicKey` and can be exported and imported as follows:

```dart
String p256 = 'secp256r1';
AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> kp = generateKeyPair(curve: p256);

// Export
BigInt d = (kp.privateKey as ECPrivateKey).d!;
BigInt x = (kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.x!.toBigInteger()!;
BigInt y = (kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.y!.toBigInteger()!;

// Import
ECDomainParameters domain = ECDomainParameters(p256);
ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey = ECPrivateKey(d, domain);
ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = ECPublicKey(domain.curve.createPoint(x, y), domain);
```

Here `d` is the raw private key and `x` and `y` are the x and y coordinates of the raw public key.

---

On the JavaScript side, the Base64 encoded raw private key is used and the Base64 encoded raw uncompressed key, where the uncompressed key is the concatenation `0x04 + <x> + <y>`. So, for export and import, the following applies:

- Regarding the export, the Base64 encoded raw private and public key can be derived from `d`, `x`, and `y` as follows:

  ```dart
  String rawPrivateB64 = exportPrivate(d);
  String rawUncompressedPublicB64 = exportPublic(x, y, 32);
  ```

  with

  ```dart
  import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:nanodart/nanodart.dart';

  String exportPrivate(BigInt d){
    return base64Encode(NanoHelpers.bigIntToBytes(d));
  }

  String exportPublic(BigInt x, BigInt y, int size){
    return base64Encode(NanoHelpers.concat([Uint8List.fromList([4]), pad(NanoHelpers.bigIntToBytes(x), size), pad(NanoHelpers.bigIntToBytes(y), size)]));
  }

  Uint8List pad(Uint8List list, int size){
    Uint8List padded = list;
    int currSize = list.length;
    if (currSize < size){
      Uint8List pad = Uint8List(size - currSize);
      padded = NanoHelpers.concat([pad, list]);
    }
    return padded;
  }
  ```

  The size passed in `exportPublic()` as 3rd parameter is the size of the order of the generator point (32 bytes for secp256r1). If `x` or `y` are smaller, they are each padded from the front with 0x00 values until the required length is reached.

  For the conversion from `BigInt` to `Uint8List` and the concatenation I used the [`NanoHelpers`](https://pub.dev/documentation/nanodart/latest/nanodart/NanoHelpers-class.html) class from the *NanoDart* package for simplicity. Of course, other implementations can be used here as well.
- Regarding the import, `d`, `x`, and `y` can be derived from the Base64 encoded raw private and public key as follows:

  ```dart
  BigInt d = importPrivate(rawPrivateB64);
  List xy = importPublic(rawUncompressedPublicB64);
  BigInt x = xy.elementAt(0);
  BigInt y = xy.elementAt(1);
  ```

  with

  ```dart
  BigInt importPrivate(String d){
    return NanoHelpers.byteToBigInt(base64Decode(d));
  }

  List importPublic(String xy){
    Uint8List xyBytes = base64Decode(xy);
    xyBytes = xyBytes.sublist(1, xyBytes.length);
    int size = xyBytes.length ~/ 2;
    Uint8List x = xyBytes.sublist(0, size);
    Uint8List y = xyBytes.sublist(size);
    return [NanoHelpers.byteToBigInt(x), NanoHelpers.byteToBigInt(y)];
  }
  ```

---

##### Test

The posted key pair

```
{"priKey":"CVK3r/UxdGCwQBjtn5vN/orUMxKf9E/1TlJzLkMz9t4=","pubKey":"BJH/mWJqgchGxXGA5/E79SsWRwVo3rpduBmD8FOs7UlKiK8PIvwrkCDvUcwhKdysW35OByPjoVcwFqg1NyumLKM="}
```

can be imported and used for signing and verification as follows:

```dart
String rawPrivateB64 = "CVK3r/UxdGCwQBjtn5vN/orUMxKf9E/1TlJzLkMz9t4=";
String rawUncompressedPublicB64 = "BJH/mWJqgchGxXGA5/E79SsWRwVo3rpduBmD8FOs7UlKiK8PIvwrkCDvUcwhKdysW35OByPjoVcwFqg1NyumLKM=";

BigInt d = importPrivate(rawPrivateB64);
List xy = importPublic(rawUncompressedPublicB64);
BigInt x = xy.elementAt(0);
BigInt y = xy.elementAt(1);

ECDomainParameters domain = ECDomainParameters('secp256r1');
ECPrivateKey private = ECPrivateKey(d, domain);
ECPublicKey public = ECPublicKey(domain.curve.createPoint(x, y), domain);

ECSignature signature = sign(private, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
bool verified = verify("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", signature, public);
print(verified); // true
```

---

**Edit:**
Regarding your comment: `sign()` and `verify()` are the methods you posted, but according to the changes, the keys are now passed *directly* (instead of strings) and the *actual message* is applied (instead of `[1,2,3]`) using `utf8.encode()` for UTF-8 encoding:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

ECSignature sign(ECPrivateKey privateKey, String txt) {
  SecureRandom random = _setRandom();
  Uint8List txtBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(txt));
  PrivateKeyParameter signParams = PrivateKeyParameter(privateKey);
  signer.init(true, ParametersWithRandom(signParams, random));
  ECSignature signature = signer.generateSignature(txtBytes) as ECSignature;
  return signature;
}

bool verify(String txt, ECSignature signature, ECPublicKey publicKey) {
  signer.init(false, PublicKeyParameter(publicKey));
  bool verify = signer.verifySignature(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(txt)), signature);
  return verify;
}
```

As `_setRandom()` I applied the implementation from `generateKeyPair()` instead of your implementation (i.e. a `FortunaRandom()` based CSPRNG).

Comment: all right, thanks ,I've used your methods to generate the base64 strings,what's the sign and verify functions look like

Comment: @John - See the edit section of my answer please.

Comment: all right,I miss that part,3ks

Comment: I've post all the codes, and the verify result is true, can you help me check it and give tips if there are

Comment: @John - SO is for concrete programming problems. For a code review, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better address. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

my whole code based on accepted answer

crypto.dart

```dart
import "dart:typed_data";
import "dart:math";
import 'dart:convert';

import "package:pointycastle/export.dart";
import './utils.dart';

Signer signer = new Signer('SHA-256/ECDSA');

class Crypto {
  final ECDomainParameters ecDomain = new ECDomainParameters('secp256r1');

  /// 公私钥对生成
  /// 关于公私钥encoding:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641616/how-to-convert-asymmetrickeypair-to-base64-encoding-string-in-dart
  ///

  Map generateKeyPair({curve = 'secp256r1'}) {
    var param = curve == 'secp256r1' ? ECCurve_secp256r1() : ECCurve_secp256k1();
    var keyParams = ECKeyGeneratorParameters(param);

    var random = FortunaRandom();
    random.seed(KeyParameter(this._seed(32)));

    var generator = ECKeyGenerator();
    generator.init(ParametersWithRandom(keyParams, random));

    AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> kp = generator.generateKeyPair();
    BigInt d = (kp.privateKey as ECPrivateKey).d!;
    BigInt x = (kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.x!.toBigInteger()!;
    BigInt y = (kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey).Q!.y!.toBigInteger()!;
    String rawPrivateB64 = exportPrivate(d);
    String rawUncompressedPublicB64 = exportPublic(x, y, 32);
    return {'base64Pub': rawUncompressedPublicB64, 'base64Priv': rawPrivateB64};
  }

  Uint8List _seed(size) {
    var random = Random.secure();
    var seed = List<int>.generate(size, (_) => random.nextInt(256));
    return Uint8List.fromList(seed);
  }

// TODO
// Restore the ECPrivateKey from 'd'.
  restoreKeyFromPrivate(privateKeyStr) {
    ECPrivateKey privateKey = new ECPrivateKey(BigInt.parse(privateKeyStr, radix: 10), ecDomain);
    ECPoint Q = privateKey.parameters!.G * privateKey.d as ECPoint;
    ECPublicKey publicKey = new ECPublicKey(Q, privateKey.parameters);
    return publicKey;
  }

  ECSignature sign(ECPrivateKey privateKey, String txt) {
    SecureRandom random = _setRandom();
    Uint8List txtBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(txt));
    PrivateKeyParameter signParams = PrivateKeyParameter(privateKey);
    signer.init(true, ParametersWithRandom(signParams, random));
    ECSignature signature = signer.generateSignature(txtBytes) as ECSignature;
    return signature;
  }

  bool verify(String txt, ECSignature signature, ECPublicKey publicKey) {
    signer.init(false, PublicKeyParameter(publicKey));
    bool verify = signer.verifySignature(Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(txt)), signature);
    return verify;
  }

  SecureRandom _setRandom() {
    // List<int> key = [67, 3, 241, 75, 143, 78, 115, 99, 21, 242, 180, 43, 26, 7, 194, 20];
    // List<int> iv = [87, 117, 137, 182, 2, 199, 132, 230, 120, 12, 109, 177, 34, 197, 186, 206];
    List<int> key = _seed(16);
    List<int> iv = _seed(16);
    KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(new Uint8List.fromList(key));
    ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter> paramsIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, new Uint8List.fromList(iv));
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom('AES/CTR/AUTO-SEED-PRNG')..seed(paramsIV);
    return random;
  }
}
```

crypto_test.dart

```dart
import '../lib/crypto/crypto.dart';
import "dart:typed_data";
import "dart:math";
import '../lib/crypto/utils.dart';
import "package:pointycastle/export.dart";

var crypto = new Crypto();
void main() {
  // _generateTest();
  // _signTest();
  Map keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPair();
  String rawPrivateB64 = keyPair['base64Priv'];
  String rawUncompressedPublicB64 = keyPair['base64Pub'];

  BigInt d = importPrivate(rawPrivateB64);
  List xy = importPublic(rawUncompressedPublicB64);
  BigInt x = xy.elementAt(0);
  BigInt y = xy.elementAt(1);

  ECDomainParameters domain = ECDomainParameters('secp256r1');
  ECPrivateKey private = ECPrivateKey(d, domain);
  ECPublicKey public = ECPublicKey(domain.curve.createPoint(x, y), domain);

  ECSignature signature = crypto.sign(private, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  bool verified = crypto.verify("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", signature, public);
  print('验签结果');
  print(verified); // true
}

_generateTest() {
  Map keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPair();

  print("结果");
  print(keyPair['base64Pub']);
  print(keyPair['base64Priv']);
}

_signTest() {
  // AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> kp = crypto.generateKeyPair();
  // ECSignature signature = sign(kp.privateKey as ECPrivateKey, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  // bool verified = crypto.verify("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", signature, kp.publicKey as ECPublicKey);
  // print(verified); // true
}
```